# Python 3 - Different way of writing a print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's a different way to write the following command, so that i can use a variable instead of 'line[openpos:closepos]'?

```
import re

def matches(line, opendelim='(', closedelim=')'):
    stack = []
    for m in re.finditer(r'[{}{}]'.format(opendelim, closedelim), line):
        pos = m.start()
        if line[pos-1] == '\\':
            continue

        c = line[pos]
        if c == opendelim:
            stack.append(pos+1)
        elif c == closedelim:
            if len(stack) > 0:
                prevpos = stack.pop()
                yield (prevpos,pos,len(stack))
            else:
                # error
                print("encountered extraneous closing quote at pos {}: '{}'".format(pos, line[pos:] ))
                pass

    if len(stack) > 0:
        for pos in stack:
            print("expecting closing quote to match open quote starting at: '{}'"
                  .format(line[pos-1:]))

line = '(((1+0)+1)+1)'
for openpos, closepos, level in matches(line):
    print(line[openpos:closepos])
```

Comment: Update the question by inserting my entire code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not `yield` the starting and ending index of the part you want but directly `yield` the part in your `matches` function

```
yield (line[prevpos:pos], len(stack))
```

In your `for` loop you can then do

```
for part, level in matches(line):
    print(part)
```

Comment: when i do that i am getting a syntax error saying "yield outside function "

Comment: @RandomGuy You have to replace the line `yield (prevpos,pos,len(stack))` in your function `matches` with `yield (line[prevpos:pos], len(stack))`. Check that your indentation is correct

Comment: Can i use the 'part' as an input to another function?

Comment: @RandomGuy Yes of course you can use it like any string.